# Trying to have values associated with checkboxes in a wpf listbox

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, datagrid, listbox

I am using WPF and have a listbox that is bound to a datatable that is filled at run time. The listbox uses the datatable and creates checkboxes. I want to be able to filter a datagrid by checking and unchecking these checkboxes. My stumbling block is trying to set and get values of the selected items. You can see below that I bound the selectedvaluepath of the listbox to the 'id' column of the datatable that the listbox is bound to but doing it this way only returns the value of one of the selected checkboxes.

In the code behind I could loop through the selecteditems but I don't know how to get the 'id' column through this route.

XAML for listbox:

```
        <ListBox Name="lbMatchTypeFilter" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=relationshipTypesTable.dataTable.DefaultView}" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectedValuePath="{Binding id}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="center" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" ToolTip="{Binding typeDesc}" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding displayString}" Background="{Binding color}" Margin="-4,0,0,0"/>
                    </CheckBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: What about binding an observable collection to `ListBox.SelectedItems`?  That should allow you to access all the selected items.